# Is there a way to create tables in a DB using python Dictionary?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I have a large dictionary of items - ~400 columns. I have a script to detect and create the type of each item so I have {'age' = INT, "Name" = String,etc..) but I'm not sure how to use that to create a table in SQLAlchemy or directly creating the query?

I am using postgres but I am familiar with mysql & sqlite so anything that works for those I would be able to apply to my usecase.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Creating Table from dictionary in SQLAlchemy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44937601/creating-table-from-dictionary-in-sqlalchemy)

Comment: Thank you @Błotosmętek I saw that question when I searched for a answer but I didn't see the connection in how to create the table itself. They seem to know the number of columns and type in advance, it seemed?

Comment: Ah, I see where the problem lies.

Comment: why the downvote?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about this:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, Table, Column, MetaData
metadata = MetaData()
fields = (Column(colname, coltype) for colname, coltype in your_dict.items())
t = Table(name, metadata, *fields)
engine = create_engine(database)
metadata.create_all(engine)
```

You need to have objects from `sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes` rather than strings as values in `your_dict`:

```
from sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes import String, Integer
```

See https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/core/type_basics.html for the whole list.

Comment: I tried that but i am getting this error : sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: 'SchemaItem' object, such as a 'Column' or a 'Constraint' expected, got 'String'

Comment: here's a example of how my your_dict dictionary looks like {'Code': 'String', 'Type': 'String', 'Name': 'String', 'Exchange': 'String'}

Comment: Thank you so much it worked. So cool and saved me(and hopefully others) a ton of time when creating alot of columns.